# deploying intrusion prevention system with custom plugins (snort inline)

Tags: linux, snort, intrusion-detection

I have to deploy a Snort based intrusion prevention system.

I am total newbie in this, so any kind of help , references for starters would be highly appreciated.

Also snort documentation talks about Honeynet Snort Inline Toolkit, but the available link to it is returning 404. I checked it on Honey net but couldn't find it.

Also i read in the documentation that custom plugins too can be written for snort, is there any java library for that?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Ashish

Comment: Probably more ontopic at serverfault.

Comment: deployment can be considered for serverfault but what about the java library for plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins can only be developed in C as of now and are fairly undocumented. The SnortSP platform is supposed to make this easier. It's currently in beta and can be [downloaded here](http://www.snort.org/downloads/snort-3-0/).

Now, you don't mention why would you like to write a plugin, maybe all you need are rules that are thoroughly documented in the [user manual](http://www.snort.org/assets/125/snort_manual-2_8_5_1.pdf). There are also tools that can output Snort rules from the logs of an attack, like [Nebula](http://nebula.carnivore.it/)

Comment: Ok, I was able to deploy Snort IDS (Intrusion Detection System) on my Fedora 10 virtual machine on a sun virtual box, but my requirement is to deploy Snort in IPS (Intrusion ) and I am still facing difficulty in it (like unable to drop,reject or sdrop packets according to defined rules), snort doesn't identify my reject and sdrop rules.

Comment: Problem solved , able to deploy Snort in IPS mode, there was some problem in installation methods that i was following.